# Operator != for iterators in stdlibrary

Tags: c++, iterator

It's clear why we cannot assign const_iterator to just iterator.

```
std::vector<int> v;
std::vector<int>::iterator i = v.cbegin(); //no viable convertion
```

But the fact that they'are compare equal in the `!=` operator standpoint seems very confusing.

```
std::vector<int> v;
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    v.push_back(i);
for(std::vector<int>::const_iterator i = v.cbegin(); i!= v.end(); i++)
    std::cout << *i << std::endl; //prints 0-9
```

what's the reason for such behavior of `!=` operator?

Comment: Why do you think you shouldn't be able to do that? It doesn't break const-correctness. Assigning from a const_iterator to an iterator does, which is why it isn't allowed.

Answer (score 2):

Assigning a const iterator to an iterator would break const-correctness of the iterator. Consider:

```
 typedef std::vector<int> seq;
 const seq v;
 seq::const_iterator = v.cbegin(); // Okay
 // seq::iterator = v.begin(); // Not okay, sequence is const
```

If you could assign a const iterator to a simple iterator the above example would be able to manipulate the content of a `const` sequence.

---

Comparing two iterators just tells you if they point to the same data (or the end/begin) of some sequence.

```
 typedef std::vector<int> seq;
 seq v;
 const seq& cv = v;
 cv.cbegin() == v.begin(); // Okay
 cv.cbegin() != v.begin(); // Also okay
```

Here you have a sequence and a `const` view of the same sequence. When comparing iterators of the two, two iterators pointing to the same data should compare equals.